# Using MouseDown with SuperCollider: non-GUI implementation

Tags: c++, mouseevent, supercollider, human-computer-interface

I want to use MouseDown in SuperCollider and am having a helluva time. Is it the case that only mouseDownAction actually works with anything? I want to be able to click **anywhere** on the screen, and have the mouse coordinates print, e.g., to the post window:

```
Server.default=s=Server.local;
s.boot;
s.mouseDownAction = { x = {|t_poll=0| var x_val, y_val;
    x_val = {MouseX.kr};
    y_val = {MouseY.kr};
    Poll.kr(t_poll, [x_val, y_val], ["x_val", "y_val"]);

}.play };
s.mouseUpAction = { x.set(\t_poll,1) };
```

Of course, this does not work, because mouseDownAction seems reserved as a property of the 'View' class i.e. only clicking within a specific window, as the below working [albeit not quite what I want] code:

```
w = Window.new("Mouse Coordinates", Rect(1300,600,50,50));
b = Button.new(w,Rect(10,10,40,25)).states_([["off"],["on"]]);
b.mouseDownAction = { x = {|t_poll=0| var x_val, y_val;
    x_val = {MouseX.kr};
    y_val = {MouseY.kr};
    Poll.kr(t_poll, [x_val, y_val], ["x_val", "y_val"]);
}.play };
b.mouseUpAction = { x.set(\t_poll,1) };
w.front;
```

Some things I want to know:

1. Can I modify the first snippet to actually work?
2. Is there a way to get MouseDown to work to give me these coordinates as I click anywhere on the screen?
3. How can I figure out how to 'get' the mouse coordinates (calling on which functions [already tried 'output', 'postln', &.c])?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: Because sc is written in c++ & i would imagine there is alot of overlap between the people who use supercollider and who are into deep c++ audio dev

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ugen for the mouse button https://doc.sccode.org/Classes/MouseButton.html

This is the example from the linked helpfile:

```
(
SynthDef( \mousexyb, { |out=0|
    var mousex, mousey, mousebutton;
    mousex = MouseX.kr( 500, 1000 ); // this will determine the frequency of the sound (minimum value, maximum value, warp, lag)
    mousey = MouseY.kr( 0, 0.3 ); // this will determine the amplitude of the sound
    mousebutton = MouseButton.kr( 0, 1, 2 ); // this will turn the sound on or off (minimum value, maximum value, lag)
    Out.ar( out, SinOsc.ar( mousex, 0, mousey ) * mousebutton );
}).add
)
```

What you could do is have the server generate an OSC message when the button is pressed and have the language listen for that.

Comment: My understanding is this button only works if the SC GUI window is active... if you've used this synthdef, can you confirm if that is the case?

Comment: Yes, it works even when I'm posting here. I'm on ubuntu, but this should be true for other operating systems.  You can also detect keystrokes and whatnot also, so scsynth can work as a full keylogger/snooping widget.